# Contraint sql error: #1005 - Can't create table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, constraints

Error
I have a working site in one server. I decided to move it to another company. I exported the database with phpmyadmin and uploaded in the new server. Everytime I try to import the database I receive this error:

SQL query:

```
--
-- Constraints for table `seller_cart`
--
ALTER TABLE `seller_cart`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `seller_cart_ibfk_1`
    FOREIGN KEY ( `subscription` )
      REFERENCES `subscription` ( `id` ) ,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `seller_cart_ibfk_2`
    FOREIGN KEY ( `user` ) 
      REFERENCES `users` ( `user_id` )
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE ,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `seller_cart_ibfk_3`
    FOREIGN KEY ( `featured_item` )
      REFERENCES `featured_item` ( `item` )
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE ;
```

MySQL said: Documentation

```
#1005 - Can't create table 'project123.#sql-12050_1d' (errno: 150) (Details...)
```

***HERE'S THE STRUCTURE OF seller cart:***

```
--
-- Table structure for table `seller_cart`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `seller_cart` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `subscription` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `item_listings` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `featured_item` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `quantity` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `price` float NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `user` (`user`),
  KEY `subscription` (`subscription`),
  KEY `featured_item` (`featured_item`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

---

What could be the problem? I just exported and imported the samedatabase. Even tried on a localhost and the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

This error is thrown when you are trying to refer a column which is not indexed.

Check if

1. subscription ( id )
2. users ( user_id )
3. featured_item ( item )

have valid indexes defined. If not, define them and run your `ALTER ...` statement.

***Refer To***: Rules for Foreign Key Constraints:

- [InnoDB and FOREIGN KEY Constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)

Comment: STRUCTURE:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `seller_cart` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `subscription` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `item_listings` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `featured_item` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `quantity` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `price` float NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `user` (`user`),
  KEY `subscription` (`subscription`),
  KEY `featured_item` (`featured_item`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

Comment: Well, indexes must be defined in parent table on parent columns.